# How to transform Date format d.m.yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy in SAS?

Tags: date, sas, leading-zero

I have an input file, where my dates don't have leading zeros (like 25.3.2016) but I would like to transform them into format DDMMYYYYP10.

Is there any format, informat, function etc. that could do that for me?

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 4.3.

Comment: Have you tried changing the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My input is dataset, so this worked for me:

```
data dates; 
    set My_data;
        format date1 DDMMYYP10.;
        date1 = input (date, anydtdte10.);

run;
```

Comment: So in that case your Date variable did not actually have a numeric SAS date. It was a character variable with a text value, and you are using the INPUT function to convert that text value into a numeric date value.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any "transformation" required, really. The only two things you need are:

1. A proper informat (in your case, the `ANYDTDTE10.` should do) for SAS to adequately recognize the dates upon reading the data
2. An output format (you are asking for `DDMMYYP10.`) to display dates, given they are imported correctly with the informat above.

Illustration:

```
data dates;
  format mydate DDMMYYP10.;
  input mydate ANYDTDTE10.;
  datalines;
25.3.2016
run;

proc print;run;
```

Results:

```
Obs mydate 
1   25.03.2016
```

Of course you'll be needing an `INFILE` statement rather than a `DATALINES` if you are reading external data (which I assume is your case), but the results will be the same.

Remember that output formats are *only formats*. You can change them at will without affecting the underlying data. So the key here is really the **informat**.

Answer (score 0):

SAS is designed to store a date as a "SAS Date", which is a numeric variable that is the number of days since Jan 1, 1960.  Assuming you have a SAS date (and not a character variable that looks like a date), it should be straight forward to change the format used for this variable.  Note that this doesn't actually transform the value, it just changes the format used to display the value when it is printed etc.

```
36   data want;
37     mydate="1Mar2016"d;
38     put mydate=;
39     format mydate ddmmyyp10.;
40   run;

mydate=01.03.2016
```

Edit: I reread your question and realized maybe you do not have a SAS dataset as input but instead have a text file?  If so, you can read dates like 25.3.2016 using the ddmmyy10 informat.  Below uses ddmmyy10 informat to read in the value from text file, and then ddmmyyp10 format to format it with period separators :

```
115  data want;
116    input mydate ddmmyy10.;
117    put mydate=;
118    format mydate ddmmyyp10.;
119    cards;

mydate=01.03.1960
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 1 observations and 1 variables.

121  ;
122  run;
```